# Hadoop WritableComparable<T> RawType, What is RawType

Tags: java, hadoop

Could you please explain what is RAW Type in Java, I could find anything more meaningful in the Internet. 
For ex:

Hadoop `WritableComparable<T> RawType`, What is RawType ? When I try to implement this interface using implements keyword, I was forced to give parameter in the angle brackets. 
Not sure, what is RAW type and <> angle brackets has to be used instead of () ?

Comment: search for Java generics

Answer (score 0):

Raw type is like using `Object` type everywhere. I'll use the example of `List`:

```
List list1 = new ArrayList(); //raw list
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(); //parametrized list
```

you can put whatever you want to `list` whether you can only put `String` objects to `list2`. Raw list might be convenient sometimes but it's likely to cause problems in future. Essentially raw type in Java means no type specified. If you ever feel like you need to use raw type imho probably there is something you can do to prevent it.

As for `<>` - angle brackets are used to specify type. You are mistaken by thinking you use them instead of `()`,

`<>` specify generic type, `()` mean a method (or contructor) call which you need to initialize the object.